# Does it make sense to resize images in the backend for single page web applications?

Tags: angularjs, backend, single-page-application

I'm currently implementing a single page web app with angularjs (just to get to know angular). Now I want to be able to create some content (currently a recipe) and let the user upload it. I thought it will be nice if the user could also add a picture. But what I am unsure about is, if it makes sense to create a resource which can give the picture in a particular size (resize it on the backend or get a matching cached version) in a single page application?
Wouldn't it be enough to simply downscale the image to the biggest size I currently need for my layout (and probably save the original in case I need it bigger) and let the client app handle the sizing via the img tag properties?
Or is there an important reason I'm currently missing why it is important to always deliver perfeclty sized images?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many server side technologies can resize images before serving them to a browser/client.  This way you would store the max size and allow the server to produce the one your app needs.  The reason you may not want to auto scale them is if they are large it can take a long time to download them.  You could also save different sized images when the user uploads them.  Just depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your larger image size is 800x600 pixels (which is already very small by today's standards), and that a typical JPG of this size is 120 KB.

Now suppose you want to display a page full of thumbnails (let's say there are 100 thumbnails in your page).

The browser will have to download 100 * 120KB = 12MBs. Where I live, with a decent ADSL line, that takes 30 seconds.

Now let's say you reduce the images to the target thumbnail size, which makes each thumbnail 25KB. That makes a total of 2500 KBs to download, which reduce the time to load the whole page to 6 seconds, to diaplay exactly the same information.

And if you pay for your server bandwidth, you'll see a similar reduction in cost as well.

So yes, it's a good idea to reduce the image sizes. Especially if your largest image size is big. If you take the same example and start with a 1280x960 image, you'll start at something like 500 KB per image, and make it more than 2 minutes to see your thumbnails.

And I don't even talk about rural or less-developed regions, where the bandwidth is much less than mine.